# Fetch data with React Native from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

Hello everyone I am new on ReactNative and I am just developing a basic manager app that allows users to create employee and see a list of all the employees. 
I am using React, Redux and Firebase.

I understand that firebase just returns Object from the database and so we need to convert it to an array, I used Lodash to do that but that was not a success.

Working on Mac OS Mojave

Here is my action creator code

```
export const employeesFetch = () =>{
const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();

return(dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/employees`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({type: EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val()});
    })
 };
};
```

Here is my reducer

```
import {
EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/type';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEES_FETCH_SUCCESS:
        console.log(action);
        return action.payload;
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

Here is my EmployeeList component

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FlatList, View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {employeesFetch} from '../actions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class EmployeeList extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.employeesFetch();

}

renderItem(employee) {
    return <ListItem employee={employee} />;
 }


render(){
    return (
        <FlatList
            data = {this.props.employees}
            renderItem = {this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor= {employee => employee.uid}

            />
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { uid };
  });

  return { employees };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {employeesFetch}) 
  (EmployeeList);
```

And Here is my ListItem component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {CardSection} from './common';

class ListItem extends Component {


    render() {
        console.log('HERE' + this.props.employee);
        const {name} = this.props.employee;

        return(
            <CardSection>
                <Text>
                    Name : {name}
                </Text>

            </CardSection>
        );
    }
}

export default ListItem;
```

Here my Firebase shema and my simulator Output

[image: Firebase Database][image: Simulator Output]

As you see, the app actually displays two ListItem, so it knows that we have two elements to display but do not have access to the name property

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of bugs. The first one is in your `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { uid };
  });

  return { employees };
};
```

Here, you are creating a mapped array of indexes [0,1,2,3...] and throwing away all of the other parts of each employee.

You need to (at least) return your `name` as part of your `employees` mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const employees = _.map(state.employees, (val, uid) => {
    return { uid, 
             name: val.name
    };
  });

  return { employees };
};
```

Secondly, `renderItem` gets passed an `item`, not an `employee`. You also need to destructure it out:

```
renderItem({item}) {
    return <ListItem employee={item} />;
 }
```

Comment: how can i access to this value in my ListItem component ?

Comment: When i am wrapping my employee inside {} i am getting new error : TypeError : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: What do you see if you add console.log(employee) in your renderItem({employee})?

Comment: i write like this : console.log('EMPLOYEE ' + employee); and i got " EMPLOYEE undefined " in my console log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197495/discussion-between-mickael-zana-and-will-jenkins).